# Is there something akin to malloc_trim under Solaris?

Tags: c, linux, memory, malloc, solaris

With GNU/Linux I can call malloc_trim to try and shrink the heap. Is there a similar function available on Solaris (10 in my case, but 11 is fine as well)?

Comment: I've never seen one.  Probably because it's not useful functionality.  If you *need* that level of control over memory usage, `malloc_trim()` is not sufficient since it's not guaranteed to do anything.  And if you don't need that much control over memory usage, you don't need it.

Comment: `malloc_trim` is a GNU extension. What compiler do you use on Solaris?

Comment: @Koshinae gcc. but the manual of gnulib says that malloc_trim is unavailable on solaris, osx and other platforms.